# Запросы лучше объднять с помощью JOIN или делать под запрос

Tags: mysql, производительность

При выполнения запроса, необходимо достать одно поле с другой таблицы. Для этой цели, что лучше использовать `JOIN`, или подзапрос?

Например:
1. `SELECT a.*, b.col FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b a.type = b.type`
или
2. `SELECT a.*, (SELECT b.col FROM table_b b WHERE b.type = a.type) as col FROM table_a`

Comment: Запросы - неэквивалентны. Вопрос в ТАКОЙ постановке не имеет смысла.

Comment: В общем - есть условия, при которых коррелированный подзапрос лучше, есть те, при которых он хуже, есть случаи, когда оба подхода сравнимы.